# onFocusChange is not working for me

Tags: android

I want to disappear the keyboard when the focus goes out of the TextEdit box. I have throughly searched stackoverflow and google for an answer and have tried every single response/article I have seen but nothing seems to work for me.

As many, I am very new to Android development. I must be overlooking some minor detail to no avail.

My current implementation (again, I have tried many solutions) is as follows:

My class implements `OnFocusChangeListener`. `OnCreate` after calling super and `setContentView` I do:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_box);<br> editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) { Log.d(TAG, "--> onFocusChange"); }
```

But I never see that Log message.

Sometimes I think that onFocusChange is not what I think it is. My idea is that when we touch the textedit field this view gets the focus, and when you touch any other area of the screen, say a button/listbox/etc the textedit losses the focus and onFocusChange should be called, but it is not, I never see the log entry.

Perhaps it is useful to clarify that I am using Android Studio and created an app that uses fragments.

So, I am doing this on the Detail Activity which in turn is part of a fragment. I have also tried to do it on the onActivityCreated of the fragment.

Neither approach works for me.

Any ideas what I can be missing here?

I would really appreciate your comments.

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: No error. Just I do not see the Log.d message. Which means the onFocusChange event is not being executed.

Comment: you want to hide your keypad after finish your text right?

Comment: Prabhakaran, I want to hide the keyboard when I touch anywhere outside the textedit box. The first thing I need to do is to detect when this happens, then I will deal with the keyboard after I get onFocusChange event working. But I have not been able to do so. :(

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

try doing that first?

You need to have the field be focusable before you can have the Focus Events fire on it.  But i guess it didn't help you in this case :(

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: No. The onFocusChange event does not fire up.

Answer (score 0):

`edittext.requestFocus();`

or

**Try this :**

```
       EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
       editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
            if (hasFocus == true){
                edittext.requestFocus();
            }
            else{
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: As I said, nothing seems to work for me. The onFocusChange event does not get fired up. :(  I will leave this for later. Thanks a lot guys for all your support.

Comment: @MarvinAguero did u check this

Comment: Yes, I did. onFocusChange does not get called. :(

Answer (score 0):

onFocusChangeListener is an interface which when you try to implement it as you did you also need to pass the context you wanna be Observed, so in practice one of the view elements of your ViewHolder must be Observed. so you can do it like:

(Assuming that you want to check when your EditText got focused)

```
editText.onFocusChangeListener = this
```

even if you are in an Adapter or ViewHolder while you are implementing OnFocusChangeListener you can assign that corresponding class to that Context you wanna be supervised in case of focus changes.